# Django LoginRequiredMiddleware continuingly requests reload on the login page

Tags: python, django, django-middleware

I implemented Django's LoginRequiredMiddleware and it seems to work fine basically. My only problem is, when I'm at the login page I get multiple reload requests per second.

[image: Screenshot of the terminal showing "GET /reload/events/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 and "GET /login?next=/reload/events/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1888 over and over again]

In the settings I included the login url and the middleware

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware", 
    "login_required.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware", #<- it's here
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
    "django_htmx.middleware.HtmxMiddleware",
    "django_browser_reload.middleware.BrowserReloadMiddleware",
]
LOGIN_URL = "/login"
```

and this is my view function

```py
@login_not_required
def login_page(
    request,
) -> HttpResponseRedirect | HttpResponsePermanentRedirect | HttpResponse:
    if request.method == "POST":
        username: str = request.POST.get("username")
        password: str = request.POST.get("password")

        user: AbstractBaseUser | None = authenticate(
            request, username=username, password=password
        )

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect("landingPage", username=username)
        else:
            messages.info(request, "Username or password is incorrect!")

    return render(request, "a[...]/login.html")
```

I can't find a reason why this happens and would prefer it not to happen to reduce traffic for my app.

Comment: You need to show us this login required middleware to identify the issue.
While it seems to be that there is no exception for the login page and this is causing the infinite redirect

Comment: @Mounir I followed the tutorial in https://pypi.org/project/django-login-required-middleware/ and didn't implement my own middleware class, but I've seen it in some examples. Is it necessary, to implement a custom one?